# C# - Creating multiple lists based on int in Console

Tags: c#, .net, list, for-loop

I want to create multiple lists from a given size. Imagining it could look something like this :

```
int Size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
{
    List<string> ListName + i = new List<string>();
}
```

So for example if `size = 5` I'd get 5 lists :

```
ListName0
ListName1
ListName2
ListName3
ListName4
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a container for the lists outside your loop:

```
int Size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

List<List<string>> listContainer = new List<List<string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
{
    listContainer.Add(new List<string>());
}
```

You can access them via the index of the container object. For example `listContainer[0]` would be the first `list<string>` in the container.

Here is an example of accessing one of the lists and then accessing a value from said list:

```
int Size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

List<List<string>> listContainer = new List<List<string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
{
    listContainer.Add(new List<string>());
}

listContainer[0].Add("Hi");
Console.WriteLine(listContainer[0][0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

the common way is to use a dictionary

```
    var list = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    int size = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            list["Name"+i.ToString()] = new List<string>();
```

how to use

```
    list["Name1"].Add( "hello world");
```